# Eclipse dieing on start up

Tags: eclipse

Came into work this morning and when I try to start Eclipse (Helios) I get the workspace launcher display and after clicking on OK - the startup process dies. The log file contains the stacktrace I've listed below.

I've looked in the workspace .metadata directory and the folder org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.provisional.commons.ui does not exist. I've been to my backups from last week when Eclipse was working and that folder does not exist in the backup copies either.

How do I get Eclipse to start now?

```
!SESSION 2013-02-01 09:18:10.843 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.7.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product     org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-02-01 09:18:20.906
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle     org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui (651).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TasksUiPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:232)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1197)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:904)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.util.Util.safeLoadExecutableExtension(Util.java:879)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:111)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.getContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:104)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createControl(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:206)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.fill(ControlContribution.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:353)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.createControl(ToolBarManager.java:111)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager$ToolBarTrimProxy.dock(TrimContributionManager.java:88)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager.update(TrimContributionManager.java:265)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3836)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3847)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1130)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.java:623)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.createWindowContents(WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:268)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1016)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$22.runWithException(Workbench.java:1208)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/provisional/commons/ui/CommonFonts
at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TasksUiPlugin.start(TasksUiPlugin.java:550)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
... 69 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.provisional.commons.ui.CommonFonts
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 73 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/provisional/commons/ui/CommonFonts
at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TasksUiPlugin.start(TasksUiPlugin.java:550)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:232)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1197)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:904)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.util.Util.safeLoadExecutableExtension(Util.java:879)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:111)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.getContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:104)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createControl(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:206)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.fill(ControlContribution.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:353)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.createControl(ToolBarManager.java:111)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager$ToolBarTrimProxy.dock(TrimContributionManager.java:88)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager.update(TrimContributionManager.java:265)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3836)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3847)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1130)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.java:623)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.createWindowContents(WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:268)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1016)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$22.runWithException(Workbench.java:1208)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.provisional.commons.ui.CommonFonts
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 73 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-02-01 09:18:20.906
!MESSAGE Class load Failure: 'org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TaskTrimWidget'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2013-02-01 09:18:20.921
!MESSAGE Class load Failure: 'org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TaskTrimWidget'
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TaskTrimWidget.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:904)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.util.Util.safeLoadExecutableExtension(Util.java:879)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:111)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.getContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:104)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createControl(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:206)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.fill(ControlContribution.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:353)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.createControl(ToolBarManager.java:111)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager$ToolBarTrimProxy.dock(TrimContributionManager.java:88)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager.update(TrimContributionManager.java:265)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3836)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3847)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1130)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.java:623)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.createWindowContents(WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:268)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1016)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$22.runWithException(Workbench.java:1208)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui (651).
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:121)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:232)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1197)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
... 51 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TasksUiPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/provisional/commons/ui/CommonFonts
at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TasksUiPlugin.start(TasksUiPlugin.java:550)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.provisional.commons.ui.CommonFonts
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 73 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2013-02-01 09:18:20.921
!MESSAGE Plug-in org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TaskTrimWidget.
!STACK 0  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui (651).
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:121)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:232)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1197)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:904)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.util.Util.safeLoadExecutableExtension(Util.java:879)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:111)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.getContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:104)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createControl(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:206)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.fill(ControlContribution.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:353)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.createControl(ToolBarManager.java:111)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager$ToolBarTrimProxy.dock(TrimContributionManager.java:88)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager.update(TrimContributionManager.java:265)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3836)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3847)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1130)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.java:623)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.createWindowContents(WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:268)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1016)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$22.runWithException(Workbench.java:1208)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Answer (score 6):

Did you try to use eclipse -clean (eclipse.exe -clean) ?

Other point, maybe your workspace is corrupted, you can rename it, to force eclipse to create a new one. Afterwards you can import projects from the old one.

Comment: eclipse -clean has been tried - makes no difference. I was hoping for a solution other than re-creating the workspace - whenever I've been down that path before it's only led to a world of pain

Comment: Did you install a plugin before it dies?

Comment: No - just closed it own last night as normal

Comment: Did you see http://eclipse.1072660.n5.nabble.com/Workbench-fails-to-start-Plug-in-org-eclipse-mylyn-tasks-ui-was-unable-to-load-class-org-eclipse-mylt-td134522.html

Comment: No - I hadn't seen that - but in the mean time I found this http://blog.sarathonline.com/2012/05/eclipse-indigo-without-mylyn.html which has got me going again.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Creating a new workspace and importing the project from the old workspace to the new one was the only thing that worked.